# Compression of Keys in std::map or similar data structure

Tags: c++, compression, key-value, stdmap

Lets assume I want to have a key value store in C++. Lets further assume that I have 1,000,000 unique keys which are mapped to only 100 values, but each key has one of these 100 values.

Is there an efficient way in C++ to exploit that many values exist more than once in order to compress this lookup table?

Somehow in my head it boils down to Boolean logic minimization... but it would be interesting to see if there exists any library or data structure for C++.

Comment: The answer will be vastly different in the case where all keys are numerically consecutive, or whether they are all over the place.

Comment: How would you compress it though (in general, certain special cases can exist). You still need to store ALL the keys and something that describes which of the values is associated with the key, furthermore, you need to store all the bloat related to a `map`. The only compression you can achieve is replacing values with an index if the value type is very large. That way you avoid unnecessary copies of the value type.

Comment: What is the objective here? What operations do you want to perform? Insert lots of things then iterate through all values? Look up lots of values? Mixed insertion and lookup? In the general case there is not much more than @Qubit said - you can store e.g. a pointer to your values in the map, but `std::map` still has a ton of overhead - but maybe there is a good solution if you need to only perform very specific operations.

Answer (score 0):

If size of value is bigger than size of pointer, then you can keep pointers/references instead of values.

Concerning compressing look up table, the only viable solution I see is case when you fill map only once, and then perform only read operations (value change is possible, but no additions). If this is the case, then you can use standard hash and trim key values so, that for each bucket keys kept to minimal length needed to distinguish them. This is of course assuming you can compare incomplete keys, i.e. `string`s or similar objects.